# Forecasting stocks with LSTM in Keras (Python 3.7, Tensorflow 2.1.0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I'm trying to use LSTM to predict how the Dow Jones Industrial Average will perform in coming months. I think it is appropriate to frame this as a time series scenario since the DJIA behaves like a stock, with my data values spread evenly in time. I'm only a beginner, so starting simply with only one feature (daily close value). Now I know that stocks are very random and it's hard to predict them well. And, the close value alone is not very informative... but I'll add other features later.

**Dataset:** DJIA historical data, Jan 28, 1985 - Jun 24, 2020, downloadable here: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EDJI/history?p=%5EDJI.

Visualization with matplotlib:

[image: DJIA Close Values, January 1985 through June 2020]

I use a series of close values (number = 'sequence_length') to predict the close value that immediately follows the series (sequence_length + 1). For example, I use days 0-29 to predict day 30, days 1-30 to predict day 31, etc. Put another way, I partition the data such that x_train[0] contains close values for days 0-29, and y_train[0] contains the single value for day 31. Ok. So this is the result I get after running the model on my ***test*** data:

[image: Predicted vs. Actual DJIA Test Close Values]

Ostensibly great, but I'm wondering if this whole concept is flawed: is the model merely seeing the data repetitively, and not learning any underlying pattern? See below for DJIA close predictions for 7/2020 through 4/20201. It seems to me that the prediction curve mimics the exact shape of the testing data, falling below 20,000 points and all...

[image: Predicted DJIA Close Values for 7/2020 through 4/20201]

**Questions**

1. Is this model valid? Is it a matter of changing parameters or reformatting data?
2. How the heck do you evaluate a model like this? Apparently 'accuracy' is an invalid metric. See below for loss curve
3. It was suggested that instead of using scalar close values for labels, I use sequences instead. For example, x_train[0] might include close values for days 0-29, and y_train[0] would include close values for days 30-60. I have been trying in vain to make this work and apparently have no idea how. I tried to make y_test and y_train Numpy arrays including arrays of sequence data - like this:

```
y_train, y_test = [], []
    
for i in range(sequence_length, len(training_set_scaled)):
    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i + sequence_length: sequence_length*2 + i, 0])
    y_test.append(testing_set_scaled[i + sequence_length: sequence_length*2 + i, 0])
    
y_train = np.array(list(y_item for y_item in y_train))
y_test = np.array(list(y_item for y_item in y_test))
```

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

[image: Test and Train Loss vs. Epoch]

Any help would be SO greatly appreciated, and perhaps we can all benefit ($). Joking... sort of.

**The Code**

```
df = pd.read_csv('DJIA_historical_data.csv') # 2D. Shape: (8924 examples, 7 features)
close_data = df['Close'] # 1D (examples, )
dates = df['Date'] # 1D (examples, )
adj_dates = mdates.datestr2num(dates) # Convert Pandas series to np array so matplotlib can plot

# Important parameter
sequence_length: int = 90 # Aka 'timesteps', or number of close values used to make each new prediction

# Split off the training set and scale it. 
percent_training: float = 0.80
num_training_samples = ceil(percent_training*len(df)) # A whole number
training_set = df.iloc[:num_training_samples, 5:6].values # 2D, shape: (samples, 1 feature)
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
training_set_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(training_set) #Shape is 2D: (num_training_samples, 1)

# Build 3D training set. Final shape: (examples, sequence_length, 1) 
x_train = np.array([training_set_scaled[i - sequence_length:i, 0] for i in range(sequence_length, len(training_set_scaled))]) 
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))

# Build test sets
num_testing_samples: int = len(df) - x_train.shape[0] # Scalar value
testing_set = df.iloc[-num_testing_samples:, 5:6].values # 2D (examples, 1)
testing_set_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(testing_set) # 2D ndarray (examples, 1)

x_test = np.array([testing_set_scaled[i - sequence_length:i, 0] for i in range(sequence_length, len(testing_set_scaled))])
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1)) #3D shape: (examples-sequence_length, sequence_length, 1). 

# Build 1D training labels (examples, )
y_train = np.array([training_set_scaled[i, 0] for i in range(sequence_length, len(training_set_scaled))])
y_test = np.array([testing_set_scaled[i, 0] for i in range(sequence_length, len(testing_set_scaled))]) # (examples-sequence_length, 1)
y_test = np.reshape(y_test, (y_test.shape[0])) #1D (examples, )

# Build Model
epochs: int = 150
batch_size: int = 32

LSTM_1 = LSTM(
    units = 5, # I reduced model complexity because I thought it would reduce overfitting. No such luck
    input_shape = (x_train.shape[1], 1),
    return_sequences = False,
    )

LSTM_2 = LSTM(
    units = 10
    )

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM_1) # Output shape: (batch_size, sequence_length, units)
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# model.add(LSTM_2) # Output shape: ?
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(1)) # Is linear activation appropriate here?
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', 
             optimizer = 'adam', 
             )

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', 
                               mode='min', 
                               verbose = 1, 
                               patience = 9,
                               restore_best_weights = False
                               )

history = model.fit(x_train,
          y_train,
          epochs = epochs, 
          batch_size = batch_size,
          verbose = 2, 
          validation_split = 0.20,
          # validation_data = (x_test, y_test),
          callbacks = [early_stopping],
          )

# Evaluate performance 
model.summary()
loss = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size = batch_size)

# early_stopping.stopped_epoch returns 0 if training didn't stop early. 
print('Training stopped after',early_stopping.stopped_epoch,'epochs.')

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model Loss vs. Epoch')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

prediction = model.predict(x_test)
prediction = scaler.inverse_transform(prediction)

y_test2 = np.reshape(y_test, (y_test.shape[0], 1))
y_test = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test2)

test_dates = adj_dates[-x_test.shape[0]:]

# Visualizing the results
plt.plot_date(test_dates, y_test, '-', linewidth = 2, color = 'red', label = 'Real DJIA Close')
plt.plot(test_dates, prediction, color = 'blue', label = 'Predicted Close')
plt.title('Close Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('DJIA Close')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Generate future data 
time_horizon = sequence_length
# future_lookback = adj_dates[-time_horizon:]

last_n = x_test[-time_horizon:,:,:] # Find last n number of days
future_prediction = model.predict(last_n)
future_prediction2 = np.reshape(future_prediction, (future_prediction.shape[0], 1))
future_prediction3 = scaler.inverse_transform(future_prediction2)
future_prediction3 = np.reshape(future_prediction3, (future_prediction3.shape[0]))
 
full_dataset_numpy = np.array(close_data)
all_data = np.append(full_dataset_numpy, future_prediction3)
plt.plot(all_data, color = 'blue', label = 'All data')
plt.title('All data including predictions')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('DJIA Close')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Generate dates for future predictions
# Begin at the last date in the dataset, then add 'time_horizon' many new dates
last_date = dates.iloc[-1] # String
timestamp_list = pd.date_range(last_date, periods = time_horizon).tolist() #List of timestamps

# Convert list of timestamps to list of strings 
datestring_list = [i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for i in timestamp_list] #List of strings

# Clip first value, which is already included in the dataset
datestring2 = mdates.datestr2num(datestring_list)

plt.plot_date(datestring2, future_prediction3, '-', color = 'blue', label = 'Predicted Close')
plt.title('DJIA Close Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Predicted Close')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:** At the start of your question, you mentioned "For example, I use days 0-29 to predict day 30, days 1-30 to predict day 31, etc. ".

**Case 2:** But in `Question 3`, you mentioned "For example, x_train[0] might include close values for days 0-29, and y_train[0] would include close values for days 30-60.".

Do you want to predict `Closed Value` of `Next Day`, or `Closed Value` of `Next 30 Days`.

For generating the Data for X and Y (Train and Test), you can use the function mentioned below:

```
def univariate_data(dataset, start_index, end_index, history_size, target_size):
  data = []
  labels = []

  start_index = start_index + history_size
  if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

  for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i)
    # Reshape data from (history_size,) to (history_size, 1)
    data.append(np.reshape(dataset[indices], (history_size, 1)))
    labels.append(dataset[i+target_size])
  return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

The Value of the argument, `history_size` will be 30 and the value of `target_size` will be 1 for `Case 1` and 30 for `Case 2` (mentioned above).

You need to call that function once for Training and once for Testing as shown below:

```
univariate_past_history = 30

univariate_future_target = 1 or 30

x_train_uni, y_train_uni = univariate_data(data, 0, TRAIN_SPLIT,
                                           univariate_past_history,
                                           univariate_future_target)
x_val_uni, y_val_uni = univariate_data(data, TRAIN_SPLIT, None,
                                       univariate_past_history,
                                       univariate_future_target)
```

Please find this [Tensorflow Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) which explains both `Univariate` (One Column) and `Multi Variate` (multiple columns) `Time Series Analysis` along with step by step Code, comprehensively.

Answering your questions in the sequence which you have asked:

1. Yes. Referring the [Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) will help.
2. Yes, `Accuracy` is an invalid metric. You can use `MAE` or `MSE`, as shown below:

   `simple_lstm_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')`
3. We should use `Numpy Arrays` instead of `Sequences`.

Please let me know if you face any other issue and we will be Happy to help you.